# Tag system to replace categories in Spring - Hibernate java project

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, tags, categories

Does anyone know how to go about designing tag system similar to the one used here, at stackoverflow?

Any links that would explain on how to go about implementing this system with hibernate/spring would be awesome.

I'm just looking for some starting point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest starting with three `Entities`, one for the object that is being tagged (is in the case of the SO example, this would be a `Post`), one for holding your tag definitions (you can just call this `Tag`), and one for mapping between the two (call this one `TaggedPost`).

Then the basic process of assigning a `Tag` to a `Post` goes something like:

1. See if a `Tag` with the given name already exists, if yes, use the existing one, otherwise insert a new one.
2. Create a new `TaggedPost` instance that links the `Post` with the `Tag` from step 1.

To remove a `Tag` from a `Post` you just delete the corresponding `TaggedPost` entity.

You can use Hibernate annotations to expose the set of tags that are applied to a given `Post` as a Java Collection so that you can just say `getTags()` to get all the tags.  And you can do the same thing on `Tag` so that you can say `getPosts()` to get all the posts that have a given `Tag`.

Answer (score 2):

aroth's answer of three entities is perfectly valid, but we do the same thing using just two entities because the third one (ie `TaggedPost`) doesn't add any value for us.

Our entities look something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Tag")
public class Tag {

    @ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(
            name="PostTag", 
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TagId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PostId")
    )
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_Tag_Post", inverseName="FK_Post_Tag")
    private Set<Post> posts;

    /* ... */ 

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "Post")
public class Post {

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(
            name="PostTag", 
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="PostId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="TagId")
    )
    @ForeignKey(name="FK_Post_Tag", inverseName="FK_Tag_Post")
    @Sort(comparator=CompareTagByName.class, type=SortType.COMPARATOR)
    private SortedSet<Tag> tags;

    /* ... */ 

}
```

The advantage is that we don't need to manually maintain the join. We simply add or remove a `Tag` from each `Post` as needed.

Note also:

- lazy fetching on `Tag.posts` is a good idea... otherwise you might cause Hibernate to unnecessarily load thousands of `Post` records each time a tag is displayed.
- the many-to-many join makes it easy to sort the tags in alphabetical order, by providing a `Comparator` with a `@Sort` annotation